# how to dissmiss a popover on button click and how to change the size

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopover

I am using UIPopover to display videos using UIImagePickerController.In this I have to dismiss my popover when use is clicked.Can anyone please help me to do this?

Also I want to change the size of the popover.Now I am using the below code to chane the size.But it is not working.Width is not getting changed.

```
[popOver1 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000.0 , 500.0) animated:YES];
```

Please give me a solution for these two problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dismissing popover controller you can use below code in button action method.

```
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

For changing the width you can change the frame of the popover controller not contentSize.

```
    popoverRect = CGRectMake(x, y, width,height);
```

i found you are trying like this

```
[popOver1 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000.0 , 500.0) animated:YES];

//it means in increases the contentSize not the width
```